# Cannot read property '_root' of null in React Native when using NativeBase Toast component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I'm using NativeBase's Toast component to show a message after successfully submitting a form, but I get this error message in the console every time I run it.

```
_onSubmit error TypeError: Cannot read property '_root' of null
    at Function.show (ToastContainer.js:79)
    at InventoryItemAdd.js:40
    at tryCallOne (core.js:37)
    at core.js:123
    at JSTimers.js:98
    at Object.callTimer (JSTimersExecution.js:95)
    at Object.callImmediatesPass (JSTimersExecution.js:199)
    at Object.callImmediates (JSTimersExecution.js:214)
    at MessageQueue.js:222
    at guard (MessageQueue.js:46)
```

Here's the JSX in my render function:

```
<Container>
    <Navbar title="Add an Inventory Item" backArrow />
    <Content keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        <InventoryItemAddForm
            onSubmit={this._onSubmit}
            data={formData}
            enableReinitialize={true}
            initialValues={initialValues}
        />
    </Content>
    <FooterTabs />
</Container>
```

And my `_onSubmit` function:

```
_onSubmit = ({name, inventoryTypeId, internalCode, description = "", measurementUnitId}) => {
    const {inventoryItemCreate, showErrors} = this.props

    return inventoryItemCreate({
        input: {
            name: name.trim(),
            inventoryTypeId,
            internalCode: internalCode.trim(),
            description: description.trim(),
            measurementUnitId,
        }
    })
        .then(({data: {inventoryItemCreate}}) => {
            dismissKeyboard()
            Toast.show({
                text: "Inventory item added successfully!",
                position: "bottom",
                buttonText: "Okay",
                type: "success",
                duration: 2000,
            })
            Actions.InventoryItemDetails({id: inventoryItemCreate.id})
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('_onSubmit error', error)
            showErrors()
        })
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I have the same issue.

Comment: I haven't found a solution that fixes this completely yet, but I think it might have something to do with multiple animations running at the same time. I managed to fix some of these areas of code by navigating scenes first and then displaying the toast in another `then` function, but I still don't know exactly why it doesn't work or why that sometimes fixes it.

Comment: I see thanks. the component is probably still bugged by itself.

Comment: Do you still find this issue with NativeBase [2.1.4](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.1.4)?

Comment: I can't get it to update past 2.1.2 even after following the guide on github.

Comment: The issue still happens on nativebase version 2.2.0.

Comment: This issue is also on  "native-base": "^2.4.5"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out the root component of the app needs to be wrapped in [nativebase's `<Root>` component](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Toast) in order for Toast notifications to work reliably.

Comment: Hey man, sup. I'm trying to figure out how to wrap my topmost component with Root using React-Native-Navigation v1 from wix. I don't have a "StackNavigator" as in the example. Do you have any idea on how to solve this? It's happening with the ActionSheet too.

Comment: Let's see... If I'm understanding correctly, the problem is that React-Native-Navigation v1 from wix uses `Navigation.registerComponent` instead of ReactNative's `AppRegistry.registerComponent` function and puts itself as the root so you can't wrap it?

Comment: Nono, i do use AppRegistry, but i was trying to wrap `<App/>` around a `<Root>` but didn't work. Either way, i ended up using another ActionSheet component called `react-native-actionsheet`.. and it worked without wrapping with Root. Thanks for replying :)